# Adding a quantifier to group

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I have the following file (I used 4 spaces instead of tabs here):

```
abc123   abc123    abc123    abc123    abc123

abc123   abc123    kaskls    abc123    kaskls
```

The alphanumeric entries are separated by tabs, and I want to get rid of the first 3 columns.
Here's what I have tried:

```
:s/\(.*\{-}\t\)\{3}//g
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
E871: Can't have a multi follow a multi !
E62: Nested \{
E476: Invalid Command
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove the star: `:s/\(.\{-}\t\)\{3}//g`

Comment: @user938271 Thanks! Can't believe I missed that! I still had some issues with this regex, but trying an entirely new regex solved it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command works:

```
:%s/\([^\t]*\t\)\{3}//
```

We match on not tabs then tabs.
This gets rid of the first 3 columns from a table.